# Android Speech to Text functionality in custom keyboard

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I made a custom keyboard which is working fine, I want to use the mic(for speech to text) in my keyboard(which also has the custom design). How can I use a button in keyboard which onClick opens the custom design of mic??

Expected output link:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just wrap the keyboard layout like this

```
<Relativelayout>
  // do other stuff and play with visibility
  <KeyboardView />
</Relativelayout>
```